# How do we retrieve all messages for a dialog without marking them as read in Android QuickBlox SDK?

Tags: android, quickblox, quickblox-android

I am using QuickBlox Android SDK.

While fetching all messages for a dialog, I do not want to mark messages as read. I tried this way but it is not working.

```
QBRequestGetBuilder customObjectRequestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("mark_as_read",1);
customObjectRequestBuilder.fillParametersMap(map);
ArrayList<QBChatMessage> messages = QBChatService.getDialogMessages(dialog, customObjectRequestBuilder, new Bundle());
```

Is there any way to achieve this? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to manage this way:

```
QBRequestGetBuilder customObjectRequestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
customObjectRequestBuilder.addRule("mark_as_read", "", 0);
```

another parameters

```
ArrayList<QBChatMessage> messages = QBChatService.getDialogMessages(dialog, customObjectRequestBuilder, new Bundle());
```

Answer (score 0):

With the method markMessagesAsRead.
If you only need mark many messages as read. It's possible to mark all messages as read - just don't pass messagesIDs (messagesIDs = null).

```
StringifyArrayList<String> messagesIDs = "ids";
QBChatService.markMessagesAsRead(dialogId, messagesIDs, new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void result, Bundle params) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException responseException) {

                }
            });
```